# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at iterateId

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know, based on this error lot of questions available in SO but my problem is bit different.

I'm using for each loop to get the id and text of the elements as below

```
function iterateId(id){

    $("input[id*='" + id + "']").each(function(){
        var idOfRadioButton = $(this).attr('id');
        var textOfRadioButton = $(this).closest("div").children("label").first().text();
        console.log(textOfRadioButton);
        console.log(idOfRadioButton);
    });

}
```

i'm passing id's from the array by using for loop as below

```
window.radioButtonOrNot = function(inputArray){

    var array = inputArray;

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        console.log("Came " + array[i]);
        iterateId(array[i]);
    }

};
```

When i'm following the above approach, getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at iterateId`. Any one know where i'm doing the mistake

**Edit**

I've included jQuery also. Following is the working scenario

```
window.setText = function(id, text){

    if($("input[id$='" + id + "']").is(':visible')){
        $("input[id$='" + id + "']").val(text);
    }
};
```

Comment: Please share a working snippet demonstrating the issue you are facing.

Comment: `$("input[id*='" + id + "']").each(function(){` this looks fishy . `id` is unique , then any reason to iterate ?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Pls check the **edit**

Comment: You must have done something that deletes the `$` global variable.

Comment: While you say that you've included jquery, that error states otherwise. It's possible that your code is running before jquery has been loaded.

Comment: @Bahu Please share a working snippet so that your issue can be replicated. Error suggests that jquery isn't loaded when that code is being executed.

Comment: @freedomn-m As your comment, i've delayed the process. Then also i'm getting the same problem

Comment: What the *exact* value of `id` when you iterate?

Comment: `radio_id` is one of the id

Answer (score 0):

As said by `freedomn-m`, may be my code is running before Jquery initialization. So, I've followed the below approach. **Following approach is not a solution, but it's an alternate way to achieve the solution**

`I've used JavaScript instead of jQuery` as below

```
var inputId = document.querySelectorAll("input[id*='" + id + "']");
for(i = 0; i < inputId.length; i++){
    console.log(inputId[i].id);

    if(document.getElementById(inputId[i].id) != null){
        console.log(document.querySelector('label[for*='+ inputId[i].id +']').innerHTML);
    }

}
```

Now everything working fine...